# find if an array contains at least two elements which differ by 1

Tags: javascript, array

*Problema:*
A de n enteros positivos, devuelve False si a contiene al menos dos elementos que difieren en 1, de lo contrario, False.

A=[9], the method should return False. A=[5,4], the method should return True.

Tengo este código y no estoy muy segura de lo que se hace dentro de la iteracion, porque en el segundo if se /2 y porque retornaría -1?

Su funcion es buscar

```
function solution(A) {
    const arr = []
    for (let i=0; i<A.length; i++){
      if (!arr[A[i]])
        arr[A[i]] = 1
      else
        arr[A[i]]++
      if (arr[A[i]] > A.length/2)
        return i
    }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: Puedes aclarar que significa 2 elementos que difieren en 1? que difieren en una unidad? puedes aclarar ese punto si A=[8,24] que debería devolver?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto un poco a tu logica:
Tengo entendido que la funcion recibe un arreglo y se debe evaluar con la condicion de que almenos dos numeros del arreglo deben de ser diferente de 1, el for evalua el arreglo y con el if verificamos si el elemento dentro del arreglo es diferente de 1, entonces lo agregamos al nuevo arreglo, ya con esto en el return podemos poner que retorne el resultado de la condicion.

```js
function alMenosDos(A){
  const arr=[]
  for (let index = 0; index < A.length; index++) {
    if (A[index]!=1) {
      arr.push(A[index])
    }
  }
  return arr.length >= 2
}
console.log(alMenosDos([1,1,5,3]))
```